# Как изменить label когда каждый раз нажму Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, label

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def TTB():
     your_tex = text1.get
     a = bytearray(your_text, "cp1251")
     b = list(map(int,a))
     for i in range (len(b)):
          if (int(b[i]) < 100):
               b[i] = "0"+ str(b[i])
     Lb1.config(text = b) ----> ошибка
     return

root = Tk()
text1 = StringVar()

but1 = ttk.Button(root, text = "perevod", command = TTB).pack()
ent1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = text1).pack()
Lb1 = ttk.Label(root, text =" ").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А что за `text1`?

Comment: Исправил ошибку

Comment: А нужно именно у Label менять? Просто непонятно к чему тут Entry, если нужно по клику нужно менять Label. И что за ошибка была? Приложите к вопросу ее

Comment: Я текст ввожу в entry по клику должен вызвать функцию и обработывает текст и этот же текст должен показываться на label

Comment: hello в entry, a на label должен быть [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполняется без ошибок:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def on_button_perevod_clicked():
    your_text = text1.get()
    a = your_text.encode("cp1251")
    b = list(map(int, a))
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] < 100:
            b[i] = "0" + str(b[i])

    label_info['text'] = b


root = Tk()
text1 = StringVar()

button_perevod = ttk.Button(root, text="perevod", command=on_button_perevod_clicked)
entry_info = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=text1)
label_info = ttk.Label(root, text="")

button_perevod.pack()
entry_info.pack()
label_info.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня питон 3.4 может быть поэтому не получается

Comment: @user270218, Не, дело в том, что у вас где-то ошибка -- что-то неполностью скопировали

Comment: Nonetype object does not support item assignment

Comment: @user270218, мой код полностью рабочий. Не зная что вы в нем изменили и как теперь он выглядит, помочь никак не получится

Comment: Даа извините и спасибо большое. Можно ещё один маленький вопрос как соединить элементы в списке не 103 102 а 103102

Comment: @user270218, попробуйте так: `label_info['text'] = ''.join(b)`. Если будет `', '.join(b)`, тогда элементы будут как: `103, 102`